# sum availibilty of user in minute

Tags: php, laravel

I want to calcul the total availability of an user:
I store availibilty like this :

And I have history of availibilty cause user can change their availibilty so I need to make the sum with this.

signupDate to first UpdateDATE and after
updateDate[i] to updateDate[i+1]
and at the end
updateDate[i+n] to now;

and get for each duration in minute :

endHours - startHours

I got json like this :
availibility object are per week

```
  {
  "2022-12-20" (date when user have signup ): [
         {
        dayNumber : 2,
        startHours:08:00,
        endHours :10:00;
        },
        {
        dayNumber : 3,
        startHours:11:00,
        endHours :16:00;
        }
    ],
        "2022-12-28" (date when user have update his availibilties): [
         {
        dayNumber : 2,
        startHours:08:00,
        endHours :10:00;
        },
        {
        dayNumber : 3,
        startHours:11:00,
        endHours :16:00;
        }
    ],
       "2023-01-01"  (date when user have update his availibilties): [
        {
        dayNumber : 5,
        startHours:05:00,
        endHours :10:00;
        },
        {
        dayNumber : 7,
        startHours:19:00,
        endHours :22:00;
        }
    ]
    
    }
```

Whats I have start for the moment :

I have count number of weeks beetwen signupDate and now :

```
$number_of_week = Carbon::parse($user->signupDate)->diffInWeeks(Carbon::now());
```

Finaly I want to get total availibilty of the user

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can loop over your availabilities and use something like `$carbonInstance->diffInMinutes($secondCarbonInstance)` to get the minutes per day and accumulate those values?

Comment: @Techno  the problem is that I have an object who contains array , I want to get array of objects. thanks

Comment: To be fair:, you say it's an array, but I say it's a json ;) If the problem is with your format, then store it in a different format. Why not, in stead of `day: x` and `start time: 15:00` etc, just store `'2023-01-11 15:00:00'` and `'2023-01-11 17:00:00'` as start and end? Makes each element only 2 long, provides options after midnight and would be easier to parse

Comment: @Techno I cant make like this cause the day is a weeknumber for example (monday...) object are availibility per week .

Comment: Allright, then do it manually, like 15:30 to 17:00 = (17*60+00)-(15*60+30) = 90 min for 1 day/slot

Comment: Yes but I dont know how to make a foreach in a json , finaly if I can get someting like [{date : 2022-12-20 , duration  : 90 min },{date : 2022-12-28 , duration  : 90 min }..]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've provided an answer for your question. Please check it out and let me know if there is something not working in your context. It's tested to it should work like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After our chat, I think I got the full picture of the problem, so lets see if we can solve this together:

I'm not sure where the json comes from, so let's just assign it to a variable for now:

```
$jsonString = '
{
  "2022 - 12 - 20": [
    {
      "dayNumber": 2,
      "startHours": "08:00",
      "endHours": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "dayNumber": 3,
      "startHours": "11:00",
      "endHours": "16:00"
    }
  ],
  "2022 - 12 - 28": [
    {
      "dayNumber": 2,
      "startHours": "08:00",
      "endHours": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "dayNumber": 3,
      "startHours": "11:00",
      "endHours": "16:00"
    }
  ],
  "2023 - 01 - 01": [
    {
      "dayNumber": 5,
      "startHours": "05:00",
      "endHours": "10:00"
    },
    {
      "dayNumber": 7,
      "startHours": "19:00",
      "endHours": "22:00"
    }
  ]
}
';
```

Then, we can run the code like so:

```
//I'm assuming that the json only contains availabilities for 1 user
//This creates an associated array out of your json
$assocArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$totalAvailabilityInMinutes = 0;
foreach($assocArray as $updatedAvailabilityAt => $availabilityArray) {
    $availabilityOfDayInMinutes = 0;
    foreach($availabilityArray as $availability) {
        $explodedStart = explode(':', $availability['startHours']);
        $explodedEnd = explode(':', $availability['endHours']);
        //Perform calculation from my comment
        $availabilityOfDayInMinutes = ($explodedEnd[0] * 60 + $explodedEnd[1]) - ($explodedStart[0] * 60 + $explodedStart[1]);
        dump("Availability of day {$availability['dayNumber']}: $availabilityOfDayInMinutes");
        $totalAvailabilityInMinutes += $availabilityOfDayInMinutes;
    }
}
dump($totalAvailabilityInMinutes);
```

Please note that I used 2 variables to store the minutes, one per day, and one accumulating the days. You can pick which one is most applicable to you.

I've tested the code locally, it should work and provide correct numbers ;)

#### Edit:

So since you already have an array, not a json, you could skip this step:

```
$assocArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Comment: First thanks for it , but I got "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" on json_decode I dont know why

Comment: Well, thats ironic, so that means you already have an array, so you should be able to skip the step `$assocArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);`, just make sure your arrayname is either `$assocArray` or rename the `$assocArray` into whatever your variablename is.

Comment: @DEVLOGIN Just let me know if it works with last comment, if not, ? I have one more alternative

Comment: Nice, thanks for the feedback and have fun codin!

Comment: sorry I have a question about this , How to get diffInWeeks beetween date on the foreach ? Finaly to get totalDuration beetwen two availibilite update. Thanks